# Change Form Submission to a PDF or Image File

Tags: php, html, image, forms, pdf

I have an HTML/PHP form that needs to get converted to a PDF or image file and would like it to be stored into an SQL Database on submission. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think your question is too broad, not enough info is provided. Also some code samples would be needed (at the very least of the form data you want converting)

Comment: why not save the data in the database and then create the PDF from it when you need it? saving a PDF as a binary field in the database sounds like too much trouble

Comment: I strongly recommend to store the plain text values in the database. On request, retrieve the required values from the database, convert them to any format and serve the binary as download.

Comment: SO [doesn't work like this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). We are not a `gimmetehcodez` community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it to a php script via the 'action' attribute on the form and generate the pdf file on the server. Then you can either save the pdf location on the database, or save the whole pdf as a BLOB type.

Some reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html